# PreparedStatementのSelectが遅い場合

Tags: java, jdbc

大量データの中でJDBCを利用して
PreparedStatement方式(?バインドモード)のselectが遅い場合
SQL改善ですかバインドモードを使用しない方向ですか？

画面の検索条件から検索結果を取得します。
次の前提条件を満足する必要があります。

1. 検索条件からSQL文を変更しない
2. 検索条件は未入力もある
3. 既存データで100万件を超える
4. 検索条件が可変のため期待するIndexも可変である

※遅い理由:実行計画を立てるときバインドされるデータが予測できないため最速の計画を利用しないからです。

Comment: 「検索条件は未入力もある」というのが気になります。その場合不要な全件検索が発生するのでは。具体的なSQLと実行計画の情報が提示されればそれについて検討は出来るかもしれませんが、これだけの情報では「SQLに問題があるならSQLを直しましょう、プリペアドステートメントをあきらめなければ回避できないならプリペアドステートメントをあきらめましょう」という話しかできません。

Answer (score 1):

お使いのDBはなんでしょうか。

DBによっては `SELECT ...FROM ... WITH (Index(index_name))`という構文がつかえたりします。(MS SQL Serverなど)

MySQLではつぎの構文

```
SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;

SELECT * FROM table1 IGNORE INDEX (col3_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

ORACLEはインデックスのヒントをコメント形式で引き渡したりしますが、だいぶ前に試したところではJDBCは引き渡せなかったです。その時はVIEWかPL/SQLで定義しました。

Comment: Oracleが基準ですが他のDBも対象になります。

Comment: Indexを指定してしまうと実行計画には影響はないでしょうか？

Comment: 期待した実行計画になるようにindexを指定するのですが、もしそれで目的が達成できないなら、具体的にどう失敗しているのか質問に書いてください。